# Combine object values in a single array by matching object fields in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've been digging around and trying to solve this issue the cleanest way possible, but haven't quite found the right approach.

I have an array of objects like so:

```
$myArray = [
    {field: "Diameter", measurement: 15, count: 4},
    {field: "Diameter", measurement: 16, count: 1},
    {field: "Diameter", measurement: 17, count: 15},
    {field: "Width", measurement: 7, count: 12},
    {field: "Width", measurement: 8, count: 8},
    {field: "Brands", measurement: "blah", count: 1},
    {field: "Brands", measurement: "doubleBlah", count: 3},
    {field: "Brands", measurement: "blah", count: 1},
    {field: "Brands", measurement: "doubleBlah", count: 3},
    {field: "Brands", measurement: "blah", count: 12}
    ]
```

and I need to combine the objects that have duplicate measurement fields and combine the counts like this:

```
$myBetterArray = [
    {field: "Diameter", measurement: 15, count: 4},
    {field: "Diameter", measurement: 16, count: 1},
    {field: "Diameter", measurement: 17, count: 15},
    {field: "Width", measurement: 7, count: 12},
    {field: "Width", measurement: 8, count: 8},
    {field: "Brands", measurement: "blah", count: 14},
    {field: "Brands", measurement: "doubleBlah", count: 6},
    ]
```

can it be done with something like array_map or something equally clean and not too verbose? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the keys being "hidden" like that, the data format known, and the way the question is written('the cleanest way possible', 'not too verbose') I'd simply go for foreach():

```
$myArray = '[
{"field": "Diameter", "measurement": 15, "count": 4},
{"field": "Diameter", "measurement": 16, "count": 1},
{"field": "Diameter", "measurement": 17, "count": 15},
{"field": "Width", "measurement": 7, "count": 12},
{"field": "Width", "measurement": 8, "count": 8},
{"field": "Brands", "measurement": "blah", "count": 1},
{"field": "Brands", "measurement": "doubleBlah", "count": 3},
{"field": "Brands", "measurement": "blah", "count": 1},
{"field": "Brands", "measurement": "doubleBlah", "count": 3},
{"field": "Brands", "measurement": "blah", "count": 12}
]';
$myArray = json_decode($myArray);

// Sort the data
$_im = [];
foreach($myArray as $item) {
    $_im[$item->field][$item->measurement] = $item->count + ($_im[$item->field][$item->measurement] ?? 0);
}

// Output it in the desired format
$res = [];
foreach($_im as $field => $fdata) {
    foreach($fdata as $measurement => $count) {
        $res []= (object) compact('field', 'measurement', 'count');
    }
}

print_r($res);
```

Process the data in an intermediary array where you can use the keys(if you don't do it that way searching for a given pair of keys later would be more complex), and then another foreach to put the result together in the desired format.

This should be enough for 2 levels. Also, it might be nice to put the code in a function to keep $_im from polluting the namespace.

`(object) []` is a simple way to cast an array into an object(stdClass), since that seems to be the format of the data in the question.

`?? 0` creates a start value for the case when the current `$_im[$item->field][$item->measurement]` isn't there yet (i.e. each time there's a new *field,measurement* pair). Shorter to write than using isset().

Comment: I can't seem to run this code on PHP 7.4.3. It works if I replace the `compact()` with `$res[]= [ 'field' => $field, 'measurement' => $measurement, 'count' => $count ];` (I still get several E_NOTICE messages)

Comment: @LSerni My bad, compact() wants the variable names, not the variables themselves.

Comment: I had to change this line to this: ```$_im[$item['field']][$item['measurement']] = $item['count'] + ($_im[$item['field']][$item['measurement']] ?? 0);``` but that did the trick and it wasn't too verbose, thank you!

Comment: @BRose Ok, so $item is an array, not an object? Sorry, I misinterpreted the data then. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

First sort the array so that all measurements to be possibly connected are contiguous; this will allow you to only check contiguous elements.

This approach makes it easier to change the field specification (also called *signature* or *syndrome*) of each record, uses less memory and is resistant to the "Schlemiel the Painter" problem in case of very long arrays.

```
$keys = [ 'field', 'measurement' ];

uasort($array, function($item1, $item2) use ($keys) {
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if ($item1[$key] === $item2[$key]) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($item1[$key] < $item2[$key]) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
// This is to be sure that the array will reencode as a JSON array
$array = array_values($array);
```

Now your array should look like this:

```
 [
    {"field":"Brands","measurement":"blah","count":1},
    {"field":"Brands","measurement":"blah","count":1},
    {"field":"Brands","measurement":"blah","count":12},
    {"field":"Brands","measurement":"doubleBlah","count":3},
    {"field":"Brands","measurement":"doubleBlah","count":3},
    {"field":"Diameter","measurement":15,"count":4},
    {"field":"Diameter","measurement":16,"count":1},
    {"field":"Diameter","measurement":17,"count":15},
    {"field":"Width","measurement":7,"count":12},
    {"field":"Width","measurement":8,"count":8}
 ]
```

Now, scan the array coalescing the counts with the same key-syndrome.

```
$j = -1;
$advance = true;
foreach ($array as $i => $row) {
    if ($j >= 0) {
        $advance = false;
        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            if ($array[$i][$key] !== $array[$j][$key]) {
                $advance = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!$advance) {
            // Row $i is a duplicate of row $j
            $array[$j]['count'] += $array[$i]['count'];
        }
    }
    if ($advance) {
        // Row $i is moved in row $j
        $j++;
        if ($j !== $i) {
            $array[$j] = $array[$i];
        }
    }
}
// All rows past j must be deleted
$array = array_slice($array, 0, $j+1);
```

Array is now:

```
[
    {"field":"Brands","measurement":"blah","count":14},
    {"field":"Brands","measurement":"doubleBlah","count":6},
    {"field":"Diameter","measurement":15,"count":4},
    {"field":"Diameter","measurement":16,"count":1},
    {"field":"Diameter","measurement":17,"count":15},
    {"field":"Width","measurement":7,"count":12},
    {"field":"Width","measurement":8,"count":8}
]
```